# In what structures does $ (-1)^2 = 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Does $ (-1)^2  = 1$ anywhere you have associativity and an inverse element?

Thanks!

Comment: In what structures does $(-1)^2$ do what?

Comment: oops.. thanks..

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188802/242) on the Law of Signs. There we see that it also is true for odd functions under composition.

Comment: Thank you @BillDubuque. So it's also true for these [Near-Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean $(-1)^{2} = 1$ for this answer. Furthermore, I assume you mean rings, not groups as in the tag, because I assume the square is the multiplicative operation, yet the minus sign refers to additive inverse. These things should be clarified.

The answer is yes. In general, we can show that $(-1)(x) = -x$ in the following way:

$x + (-1)(x) = (1+-1)(x) = 0x = 0$.

Note that the only requirement here is distributivity, guaranteed in any ring.

If we let $x=-1$, the desired result is there.

Comment: oh so it's true where you have an inverse and distributivity (not associativity..) and that's rings.. So, are there special groups where this is also true?

Comment: @Gil-Mor Repeat: *Not* groups

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense in the context of groups. What do you want $(-1)^{2}$ to mean in a group where you are using additive notation to designate the inverse as $-1$? A group only has one binary operation.

Comment: Yes I see.. Thank you very much.. have a good day..